# how could I copy tensorflow module from one computer to another?

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow

So I have computers all running on ubuntu and only one of them has python tensorflow module. I want to install tensorflow to all of them but it would be inefficient to connect every computer to the internet and install them all over again.so is there a possible efficient way to just copy paste some files from the computer to another to use this python module? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the contents of your python `site-packages` across. But if you are generally in the situation where internet access is expensive, you might find it more practical to use a caching proxy for all of your internet traffic.